# Firebase on Google Cloud -> java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider is a restricted class

Tags: java, maven, firebase, google-app-engine

I want to run the Firebase database on my App Engine Maven project. But pushing something to the database results in the following error:

```
2018-03-13 13:45:09 ERROR RunLoop:66 - Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (5.9.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.NettyWebSocketClient.<init>(NettyWebSocketClient.java:71)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$DefaultWSClientFactory.newClient(WebsocketConnection.java:435)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.<init>(WebsocketConnection.java:80)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.<init>(WebsocketConnection.java:68)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection$DefaultWebsocketConnectionFactory.newConnection(Connection.java:297)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:72)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:57)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$DefaultConnectionFactory.newConnection(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1303)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.openNetworkConnection(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:547)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.access$800(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:37)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1$1.onSuccess(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:500)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1$1.onSuccess(Context.java:67)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.getToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:66)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1.getToken(Context.java:62)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1.run(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:490)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.RetryHelper$1.run(RetryHelper.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackgroundThreadFactory$1$1.run(BackgroundThreadFactory.java:60)
```

Is this some kind of depency issue and is there a way to get this running on the Google Cloud?

Comment: Are you on App Engine Standard?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is it not running on App Engine Standard?